# PHP web service consumido por JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, webservice, soap

Necesito crear un web service simple en PHP y consumirlo desde Javascript.

No sé si debería usar Soap, nuSoap o Rest (las pruebas las hice con nuSoap).

No me funcionan ninguno de los ejemplos que encuentro. Sólo necesito la estructura básica de una petición a un método del ws que devuelva un "hola mundo" y a partir de ahí ya puedo continuar.

Las pruebas con nuSoap me mostraban el wsdl y los métodos que registraba en el ws, pero no conseguía recuperar nada.

Añado:

Tengo éste servicio:

```
<?php

require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

class predictiveUrlsPreloadService {

    public function getUrls($type) {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'GA':
                return 'Google Analytics code';
                break;
            case 'AA':
                return 'Adobe Analytics code';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("foodservice", "http://www.greenacorn-websolutions.com/foodservice");

$server->register("predictiveUrlsPreloadService.getUrls",
    array("type" => "xsd:string"),
    array("return" => "xsd:string"),
    "http://localhost/predictiveUrlsPreloadService/service.php",
    "http://localhost/predictiveUrlsPreloadService/service.php#getUrls",
    "rpc",
    "encoded",
    "Descripci");

@$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Y este cliente en php funcionando:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<?php

require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$wsdl = "http://localhost/predictiveUrlsPreloadService/wsdl.wsdl";

$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
$error  = $client->getError();

if ($error) {
    print_r($error);
}

$result = $client->call("predictiveUrlsPreloadService.getUrls", array("type" => 'GA'));

if ($client->fault) {
    print_r($result);
} else {
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        print_r($error);
    } else {
        echo $result;
    }
}

?>
```

Todo ello con su correspondiente wsdl.

Ahora, sabiendo que el ws funciona, necesito saber cómo lanzar una petición ajax desde javascript.

He probado con:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/predictiveUrlsPreloadService/service.php', 
    type: "predictiveUrlsPreloadService.getUrls",
    data: {
      'type' : 'AA'
    }, 
    success:  function (response) {
    console.dir(response);
  }
});
```

Pero solo me devuelve información del WS, ¿cómo podría replicar el cliente php en ajax?

Comment: Noark, porqué has escrito tu pregunta en ingles? Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta y traducirla para que no termine cerrada, ya que este es un sitio en español. Saludos.

Comment: Perdón, pensaba qye estaba en el foro inglés. Corregido.

Comment: Te faltó cambiar el título

Comment: Te he dejado un voto positivo y he votado la reapertura, en breve podremos ayudarte.

Comment: He redactado la respuesta y agradecería que la comentaras con cualquier duda que se te pueda plantear. He hecho una edición para acceder al servicio web SOAP directamente desde Javascript, en vez de usar PHP como puente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario tanto código para generar un servidor SOAP ni un cliente. Parece que en el proceso de copiar un ejemplo has dejado mucha información adicional que no necesitas (como la referencia a la URL `http://www.greenacorn-websolutions.com/foodservice`).

## Servidor SOAP

Para crear un servidor SOAP sencillo (sin WSDL) basta con las siguientes líneas:

```
<?php
/* Desarrollamos la clase que responderá las peticiones SOAP */
class predictiveUrlsPreloadService
{
    public function getUrls($type)
    {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'GA':
                return 'Google Analytics code';
                break;
            case 'AA':
                return 'Adobe Analytics code';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
try {
    /* Creamos la instancia del servidor SOAP */
    /*$server = new SOAPServer(null, [
        'uri' => 'http://localhost/tuservicio_soap.php',
    ]);*/
    $server = new SOAPServer(null, [
        'uri' => (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') .
            '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],
    ]);
    /* Asignamos la clase predictiveUrlsPreloadService como la que responderá al servicio */
    $server->setClass('predictiveUrlsPreloadService');
    /* Atendemos las peticiones */
    $server->handle();
} catch (SOAPFault $e) {
    echo $e->faultstring;
}
```

Uso `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` y `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` para hacer portable la aplicación PHP y que funcione tenga la URL absoluta que tenga.

## Cliente SOAP

El cliente es mucho más sencillo:

```
<?php
/* $uri = 'http://localhost/tuservicio_soap.php'; */
$uri = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') .
    '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/servidor_soap.php';
/* Creamos una instancia del cliente SOAP que accederá al servicio anterior*/
$client = new SoapClient(null, [
    'location' => $uri,
    'uri' => $uri,
]);
/* Llamamos al método getUrls. En modo sin WSDL no podemos usar $client->getUrls(...) */
$resultado = $client->__soapCall('getUrls', [
    'tipo' => $_REQUEST['type']
]);
/* Mostramos el resultado */
var_dump($resultado)
```

De nuevo he creado en `$uri` una URL en base a la del PHP actual, presuponiendo que el anterior se llamaba `servidor_soap.php`.

## JavaScript > REST > SOAP > predictiveUrlsPreloadService::getUrls

Si lo que necesitas es practicar con acceso a diferentes servicios (REST/JSON y SOAP) entonces este script PHP autónomo (no requiere ningún PHP adicional) te muestra un ejemplo de cómo realizar el proceso:

```
<?php
/* Detectamos si queremos acceder a los servicios SOAP a través de PATH_INFO (añadir ruta al PHP) */
if (empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) !== true) {
    /* Obtenemos la URL absoluta (sin tener en cuenta el puerto) del servidor */
    $base = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') .
        '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '/servidor';
    /* Implementamos el cliente y el servidor en diferentes casos */
    switch ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) {
        case '/servidor':
            /* Desarrollamos la clase que responderá las peticiones SOAP */
            class predictiveUrlsPreloadService
            {
                public function getUrls($type)
                {
                    switch ($type) {
                        case 'GA':
                            return 'Google Analytics code';
                            break;
                        case 'AA':
                            return 'Adobe Analytics code';
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                /* Creamos la instancia del servidor SOAP */
                $server = new SOAPServer(null, [
                    'uri' => $base,
                ]);
                /* Asignamos la clase predictiveUrlsPreloadService como la que responderá al servicio */
                $server->setClass('predictiveUrlsPreloadService');
                /* Atendemos las peticiones */
                $server->handle();
            } catch (SOAPFault $e) {
                echo $e->faultstring;
            }
            break;
        case '/cliente':
            /* Creamos una instancia del cliente SOAP que accederá al servicio anterior*/
            $client = new SoapClient(null, [
                'location' => $base,
                'uri' => $base,
            ]);
            /* Llamamos al método getUrls. En modo sin WSDL no podemos usar $client->getUrls(...) */
            $resultado = $client->__soapCall('getUrls', [
                'tipo' => $_REQUEST['type']
            ]);
            /* Vamos a devolver al javascript datos en JSON */
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            die(json_encode([
                'resultado' => true,
                'datos' => $resultado,
            ]));
        default:
            die(json_encode([
                'resultado' => false,
                'datos' => 'No existe la ruta solicitada',
            ]));
    }
    die();
}
?><!DOCTYPE html><html lang="es"><head>
    <title>Ejemplo REST/SOAP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head><body>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <div class="alert alert-warning" id="cargando">
        <div class="panel-body">Cargando...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    /*url: '<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>/clientte',*/
    url: '<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>/cliente',
    method: 'get',
    data: {
      'type' : 'AA',
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.resultado === true) {
            $('#cargando').removeClass('alert-warning').addClass('alert-success');
            $('#cargando > div').text('Recibido: ' + response.datos);
        } else {
            $('#cargando').removeClass('alert-warning').addClass('alert-danger');
            $('#cargando > div').text('ERROR: ' + response.datos);
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        $('#cargando').removeClass('alert-warning').addClass('alert-critical');
        $('#cargando > div').text('Se produjo un error');
    }
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

He hecho uso de `$_SERVER['PHP_INFO']` para facilitar la portabilidad del PHP y hacerlo completamente autónomo y autosuficiente, podría haberse dividido en varios PHP.

## Javascript > REST > predictiveUrlsPreloadService::getUrls

Pero probablemente desees dar acceso a la clase de manera directa, mediante REST, sin tener como intermediario un API SOAP.

En ese caso basta con implementar el siguiente código:

```
<?php
/* Detectamos si queremos acceder a los servicios SOAP a través de PATH_INFO (añadir ruta al PHP) */
if (!empty($_REQUEST['funcion']) && !empty($_REQUEST['argumentos'])) {
    /* Desarrollamos la clase que responderá las peticiones SOAP */
    class predictiveUrlsPreloadService
    {
        public function getUrls($type)
        {
            switch ($type) {
                case 'GA':
                    return 'Google Analytics code';
                    break;
                case 'AA':
                    return 'Adobe Analytics code';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    $servicio = new predictiveUrlsPreloadService();
    if (method_exists($servicio, $_REQUEST['funcion']) === true) {
        $resultado = call_user_func([
            $servicio,
            $_REQUEST['funcion']
        ], $_REQUEST['argumentos']);
    } else {
        die(json_encode([
            'resultado' => false,
            'datos' => 'No existe la función solicitada',
        ]));
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    die(json_encode([
        'resultado' => true,
        'datos' => $resultado,
    ]));
}
?><!DOCTYPE html><html lang="es"><head>
    <title>Ejemplo REST/SOAP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head><body>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <div class="alert alert-warning" id="cargando">
        <div class="panel-body">Cargando...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    /*url: '<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>/clientte',*/
    url: '<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>',
    method: 'get',
    data: {
        'funcion': 'getUrls',
        'argumentos': 'AA',
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.resultado === true) {
            $('#cargando').removeClass('alert-warning').addClass('alert-success');
            $('#cargando > div').text('Recibido: ' + response.datos);
        } else {
            $('#cargando').removeClass('alert-warning').addClass('alert-danger');
            $('#cargando > div').text('ERROR: ' + response.datos);
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        $('#cargando').removeClass('alert-warning').addClass('alert-critical');
        $('#cargando > div').text('Se produjo un error');
    }
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

En el que he hecho uso de las funciones [`method_exists`](http://php.net/method_exists) y [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) para conocer si existe un método en una clase y poder ejecutarla pasando los parámetros deseados.

## Javascript > SOAP > predictiveUrlsPreloadService::getUrls

Por último, si quieres consumir un servicio web SOAP directamente desde Javascript debes montar la petición XML y recibir el XML como hago en este ejemplo:

```
<?php
/* Detectamos si queremos acceder a los servicios SOAP a través de PATH_INFO (añadir ruta al PHP) */
$base = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') .
    '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '/servidor';
if (empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) !== true) {
    /* Desarrollamos la clase que responderá las peticiones SOAP */
    class predictiveUrlsPreloadService
    {
        public function getUrls($type)
        {
            switch ($type) {
                case 'GA':
                    return 'Google Analytics code';
                    break;
                case 'AA':
                    return 'Adobe Analytics code';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        /* Creamos la instancia del servidor SOAP */
        $server = new SOAPServer(null, [
            'uri' => $base,
        ]);
        /* Asignamos la clase predictiveUrlsPreloadService como la que responderá al servicio */
        $server->setClass('predictiveUrlsPreloadService');
        /* Atendemos las peticiones */
        $server->handle();
    } catch (SOAPFault $e) {
        echo $e->faultstring;
    }
    die();
}
?><!DOCTYPE html><html lang="es"><head>
    <title>Ejemplo REST/SOAP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head><body>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <div class="alert alert-warning" id="cargando">
        Cargando...
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
/* Función SOAP a llamar y su parámetro */
var funcion = 'getUrls';
var parametro = 'AA';
$.ajax({
    /*url: '<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>/servidor',*/
    url: '<?= $base ?>',
    method: 'post',
    data:
        /* Montamos el XML de una petición SOAP con las variables definidas anteriormente */
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
        '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' +
                'xmlns:ns1="<?= $base ?>" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
                'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
                'xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"' +
                'SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
            '<SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                '<ns1:' + funcion + '>' +
                    '<param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">' + parametro + '</param0>' +
                '</ns1:' + funcion + '>' +
            '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
        '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>',
    success: function (response) {
        /* Buscamos si existe en la respuesta la respuesta a la función llamada */
        if ($(response).find(funcion + 'Response').length === 1) {
            $('#cargando').attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
            /* Mostramos el contenido en texto del elemento "return" de la respuesta */
            $('#cargando').text('Recibido: ' + $(response).find("return").text());
        } else {
            $('#cargando').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
            $('#cargando').text('ERROR: ' + response);
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        /* Si ha habido un error en la llamada SOAP mostramos el error devuelto */
        if (response.responseXML !== undefined) {
            $('#cargando').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger').text(
                'Error SOAP: ' + $(response.responseXML).find("faultstring").text()
            );
        } else {
            $('#cargando').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger').text('Se produjo un error');
        }
    }
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con toda esa información puedo entender correctamente el funcionamiento. Desconocía que hiciese falta el código de "SOAP-ENV" Estudiaré detenidamente las opciones. Un saludo

Comment: De nada, un placer ser de ayuda. Si te surge cualquier duda en el funcionamiento házmelo saber para que lo detalle más, o si necesitas algún ejemplo adicional.